# Cannot set property '0' of undefined in 2d array

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked a lot of times, but how do I fix exactly this thing?

I have a map[][] array (contains tile ids for a game) and I need to copy it to pathmap[][] array (contains just 0's and 1's, it is a path map), however when I do so..

```
function updatepathmap(){
        pathmap = [];
        var upm_x = 0;
        while (upm_x < map.length){
                var upm_y = 0;
                while (upm_y < map[upm_x].length){
                        pathmap[][]
                        if (canPassthrough(map[upm_x][upm_y])) {

                                pathmap[upm_x][upm_y] = 1;

                        } else {
                                console.log(upm_x);
                                console.log(upm_y);
                                pathmap[upm_x][upm_y] = 0;

                        }
                        upm_y++;
                }
                upm_x++;
        }
        console.log(map);
        console.log(pathmap);
}
```

..it gives me `Cannot set property '0' of undefined` typeerror at line `pathmap[upm_x][upm_y] = 0;`

Comment: ``pathmap[upm_x]`` is undefined meaning ``pathmap`` array does not have element at the index of ``upm_x``.  ``console.log(pathmap[upm_x])`` to check.

Comment: @tiblu but I am defining it in `pathmap[upm_x][upm_y] = 0;`

Comment: Yes, but you cannot define ``pathmap[upm_x][upm_y]`` IF ``pathmap[upm_x]`` is undefined. So make sure ``pathmap[upm_x]`` is defined as an array.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Despite the `foo[0][0]` syntactic sugar, multi-dimensional arrays do not really exist. You merely have arrays inside other arrays. One consequence is that you cannot build the array in the same expression:

```
> var foo = [];
undefined
> foo[0][0] = true;
TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
```

You need to create parent array first:

```
> var foo = [];
undefined
> foo[0] = [];
[]
> foo[0][0] = true;
true
```

You can determine whether it exists with the usual techniques, e.g.:

```
> var foo = [];
undefined
> typeof foo[0]==="undefined"
true
> foo[0] = true;
true
> typeof foo[0]==="undefined"
false
```

Comment: *"Despite the foo[0][0] syntactic sugar..."* Complete quibble here, but: That's not syntactic sugar. `foo[0]` gives us the value from the first element in `foo`, and then `[0]` gives us the value of the first element from that. Nothing special to support pseudo-multi-dimensional arrays or anything. Now, `foo[0,0]` would be syntactic sugar (fortunately, we don't have that). </quibble> :-)

Comment: The step-by-step is great!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - Sorry if the term is not fully appropriate; I come from the PHP world, where similar constructs (not *this* but some others like `foo()[0]`) have not been added until recently.

Answer (score 5):

I would have thought `pathmap[][]` was a syntax error, I'm surprised you're not seeing one.

Before you can use an array at `pathmap[upm_x]`, you must create an array at `pathmap[upm_x]`:

```
pathmap[upm_x] = [];
```

This would be the first line in your outer `while`, so:

```
while (upm_x < map.length){
    pathmap[upm_x] = [];
    // ...
```

Remember that JavaScript doesn't have 2D arrays. It has arrays of arrays. `pathmap = []` creates the outer array, but doesn't do anything to create arrays inside it.

---

Side note:

```
var upm_x = 0;
while (upm_x < map.length){
    // ...
    upm_x++;
}
```

is an error-prone way to write:

```
for (var upm_x = 0; upm_x < map.length; upm_x++){
    // ...
}
```

If you use `while`, and you have any reason to use `continue` or you have multiple `if` branches, it's really easy to forget to update your looping variable. Since looping on a control variable is *what `for` is for*, it's best to use the right construct for the job.

---

Side note 2:

Your code is falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) because you don't declare `pathmap`. Maybe you're doing that on purpose, but I wouldn't recommend it. Declare your variable, and if you need it outside your function, have your function *return* it.

---

Side note 3:

[`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would make this code a lot simpler:

```
function updatepathmap(){
    var pathmap = map.map(function(outerEntry) {
        return outerEntry.map(function(innerEntry) {
            return canPassthrough(innerEntry) ? 1 : 0;
        });
    });
    console.log(map);
    console.log(pathmap);
}
```